# On the intersection of two open affine subscheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm doing exercises 3.1—3.4 in the book of algebraic geometry by Hartshorne. Meet the following question, and is  the following assertion true? 
Suppose $U_{1}=Spec A$ and $U_{2}=Spec B$ are two open affine subset of a scheme X, then
$Spec A \bigcap Spec B = \bigcup _{f \in A \bigcap B} D(f)$.

Comment: What does $A\cap B$ mean?

Comment: This is reminiscent of a fact stated in Vakil's book used to prove his "affine communication lemma." I've also seen it reffered to as "Nike's trick." The statement is that the intersection of two affine open subschemes $U_1$, $U_2$ can be covered by open subsets which are simultaneously basic open subschemes of both $U_1$ and $U_2$.

Comment: @EricWofsey intersect as sets

Comment: @catfish is the equality given above true? I want to write a explicit equality.

Comment: It only makes sense to talk about the "intersection" of $A$ and $B$ if they are both naturally subrings of some larger ring, but there is no obvious way in which this is true.

Comment: @EricWofsey what about intersect as sets? Since if the intersection is nonempty, there is some common points(i.e. prime ideals). So as sets $A \bigcap B ≠ Φ$.Of course, I feel some things wrong and am supposed to write the equality in a better way. $Spec A \bigcap Spec B = \bigcup _{D(f) \subset SpecA \bigcap SpecB} D(f)$.Is this true?Actually,it's the Nike's trick.

Comment: @Jabin Both of these don't really make any sense as is. What is your definition of $D(f)$?

Comment: @catfish distinguished open subset(or called basic open set) defined as the complement of the Zariski closed set V((f)).So $D(f)={p \in SpecR :f \notin p}$ for the prime spectrum of ring R.

Comment: @Jabin that definition agrees with mine, but that's the issue. It doesn't make sense to define $R = A\cap B$ unless $A$ and $B$ are embedded into some common larger ring.